# How to set the default error messages of EF Code First to a custom culture

Tags: ef-code-first

For example, I want to change ALL "This {0} field is required" of Application to a phrase in anothe language.

Comment: This has nothing to do with EF Code First

Answer (score 1):

This is not to do with code first its data annotation and best practice.

Already been fairly well answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993617/data-annotation-getting-errormessage-out-database)

Comment: Ok I understood this, but I want to change all messages validations without user anotations, because if I forgot to put in some property it'll produce a bug.